# info lifecycle protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script

Tags: protractor, package.json, browserstack

I'm trying to integrate protractor with browser stack.
I have added browser stack local dependency in package.json and package lock.json. while executing script I'm getting below error.

```
PS C:\Users\umohabi\Desktop\testBrowserStack> npm run test

> protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 test C:\Users\umohabi\Desktop\testBrowserStack
> protractor typeScript/config/config.js

Connecting local

C:\Users\umohabi\Desktop\testBrowserStack\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^
LocalError
    at C:\Users\umohabi\Desktop\testBrowserStack\node_modules\browserstack-local\lib\Local.js:65:20
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:285:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 test: `protractor typeScript/config/config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\umohabi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-19T06_53_02_066Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\umohabi\Desktop\testBrowserStack>
```

Debug Log :

```
silly lifecycle protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 test: `protractor typeScript/config/config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons could be incorrect [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) account credentials being passed in the config file. You may verify the same from [here](https://www.browserstack.com/accounts/settings).